# Concentration for Hamming balls

Tags: pr.probability, measure-concentration, hypercube

It is well known that Lipschitz functions on the Boolean $n$-cube endowed with the Hamming metric satisfy concentration properties. Specifically, most of their values lie in a range of width $O(\sqrt n)$.

Do similar results exist for functions on a Hamming ball of radius $\alpha n$, where $\alpha$ is, say, a constant?

My literature search gave me positive results for $\alpha = 1/2$ since such Hamming balls are in fact bi-Lipschitz equivalent to the $(n-1)$-cube. Also positive results exist for "biased coin measures" on the $n$-cube, which resemble smoothed out Hamming balls, but I wasn't able to find anything for general Hamming balls.